# Can the Pauli exclusion principle and quantum tunneling coexist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-tunneling

It is said that quantum mechanics can pass through walls. In addition, there is a possibility that the body will be disassembled and then reassembled. By the way, doesn't Pauli exclusion principle say that not only passing through walls but also teleportation is impossible? How can these two coexist?

Comment: The ability to tunnel through walls depends on a phenomenon called *superposition* and specifically that a quantum object can exist in a superposition of many position eigenstates. It isn't clear why you are suggesting that the exclusion principle has to do with this.

Comment: " a superposition of many position eigenstates" You simply mean: a wavefunction.

Comment: people love downvoting and tell you're dumb, even if the guy asking is 15yo and much smarter than them.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pauli exclusion](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pauli.html) is about the energy levels being uniquely occupied.

[Tunneling is the](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) quantum mechanical probability for a particle at a given energy level to pass a barrier.

[image: tunnelin]

there is no contradiction.